# Bug in CGRectIntegral on 64bit devices?

Tags: ios, 64-bit, core-graphics

I am seeing odd behavior with `CGRectIntegral`. This is my code:

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(75, 22, 235, 48.000000000000007);
rect = CGRectIntegral(rect);
NSAssert1(rect.size.height == 49, @"I expected 49, but I got: %f!", rect.size.height);

// works on 32 bit iPhone simulator
// throws an exception on iPhone 64 bit simulator & iPhone 5s: 
// Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException',
// reason: 'I expected 49, but I got: 48.000000!'
```

My guess is, that it has something to do with CGFloat being a float on 32Bit and a double on 64Bit – and with the presumed use of the `ceil` within `CGRectIntegral`.

- Is it a bug in Apple's code?
- How can I fix this....elegantly?